# Generate swagger v2 schema by NJsonSchema for .NET or Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

Tags: c#, json, .net, schema, njsonschema

I need to use a tool, preferably NJsonSchema for .NET to generate schemas from c# classes. The requirement is to create schemas based on swagger version 2. For example I cannot have oneOf, anyOf, etc, which are new keywords in OAS3 in the schema.
Can we specify the swagger/OAS version in the schema generator?
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that there is a setting in NJsonSchema for choosing the version:

```
var settings = new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings
            {
                SchemaType = NJsonSchema.SchemaType.Swagger2,
            };
```